# What is the necessary condition for two vector set be aligned by an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: rotations, orthogonality

Suppose there are two vector sets $A$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{f \times 3}$

If there is an orthogonal matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ can align there two vector set perfectly, e.g. $RA = B$

What is the necessary condition for A and B to satisfy that?

I know the orthogonal matrix can be solved by the orthogonal Procrustes algorithm, but that only gives the solution. I want to know the condition for A and B to make them be perfectly aligned by the $R$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since, if $R$ is an orthogonal matrix and $v\in\mathbb R^3$, $\lVert Rv\rVert=\lVert v\rVert$, a necessary condition is that $\lVert A\rVert=\lVert B\rVert$. And it turns out that [this condition is sufficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573263/prove-that-so3-acts-transitively-on-the-unit-sphere-s2-of-bbb-r3) too. That is, two vectors $A,B\in\mathbb R^3$ have the same norm if and only if there is some orthonormal matrix $R$ such that $RA=B$.